# JS / JQuery - on click show buttons for a short period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

What I need to do is show a button when the page content is clicked. This button needs to be shown only for 3 seconds, then it has to fade out automatically.

Here's a jsfiddle with an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/EuCWp/2/

here's the jquery code:

```
$("#container").click(function(){
    $("#show").fadeIn().delay(400).fadeOut();
});
```

Assume that the red box is the page content, to whom the click event is attached. The green box is the button.

The problem is that if I keep pressing the red square, the green button should stay visible, in other words the delay needs to be resetted to 0 every time I click the red square.. This is not happening in my example, as you can see that if you click 3 times in a row the red box, you'll get this behavioir

```
show, hide, show, hide, show, hide
```

instead of

```
show, keep showed, keep showed, hide
```

Any advice? Thanks in advance for any help, best regards

---

EDIT:

I'd also like to keep that button opened while hovered with the mouse.. how can I get this behaviour?

Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` :

```
(function(){
    var timer = 0;
    $("#container").click(function(){
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
        else $("#show").fadeIn();
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $('#show').fadeOut();
            timer = 0;
        }, 400);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks dystroy. What if I also need to keep that button showed on hover? How can I achieve that?

Comment: @BeNdErR I'm not sure of what you exactly want. Maybe [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/X9agv/) ?

Comment: I was looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/X9agv/1/ do you think is a good solution? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I modify your jquery code by adding a flag.

Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/EuCWp/5/

Here is the jquery new code:

```
var user_click = "on";
$("#container").click(function(){
  if(user_click=="on")
  {
      user_click = "off"
      $("#show").fadeIn().delay(400).fadeOut(function() {
          // Animation complete
          user_click = "on";
          });
      }
});
```